Django JSON file - Which file should "model": refer to?
I am trying to populate my model with the fields I have input in the json but I am unsure which file the "model": should refer to?
I assume it should be where the model is located but I always get an error when I try to load the file - Problem installing fixture '/workspace/django-film-club/film/fixtures/films.json':
film/fixtures/films.json;
[
    {
        "model": "film.movie",
        "pk": null,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Django Unchained",
            "slug": "django-unchained",
            "year": 2012,
            "genre": "WESTERN",
            "synopsis": "<p>With the help of a German bounty-hunter, a freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.<p>",
            "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
            "excerpt": "A freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.",
            "added_on": "2024-06-01T09:43:19.754Z"
        }
    },
]

film/models.py;
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'), default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENRE_CHOICES, default='horror')
    synopsis = models.TextField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

The only thing I can thnk is that that the model in the json file is incorrect, I have tried diffent names for the model: input but still doesnt seem to work.
I expected, if sucessful to load the data into the site but I still get the error.

What is the error traceback?

I recreated your app based on the information you gave. There are a couple of things that I ran into that you could check.
1. Invalid JSON
The JSON you provided film/fixtures/films.json has an extra invalid comma at the end.
[
    {
        "model": "film.movie",
        "pk": null,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Django Unchained",
            "slug": "django-unchained",
            "year": 2012,
            "genre": "WESTERN",
            "synopsis": "<p>With the help of a German bounty-hunter, a freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.<p>",
            "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
            "excerpt": "A freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.",
            "added_on": "2024-06-01T09:43:19.754Z"
        }
    }, // This one right here
]

In JSON you cannot have a trailing comma like you would see in a dict in Python
2. Make sure you have created and applied migrations.
If you get an error similar to the following one it's possible you forgot those steps.
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '~/Desktop/django/testproject/film/fixtures/films.json': Could not load film.Movie(pk=None): no such table: film_movie

To fix that problem run the following commands:
FIRST:
python3 manage.py makemigrations

SECOND:
python3 manage.py migrate

MISC

Make sure film is in settings.py
Make sure you are running loaddata command correctly:

python3 manage.py loaddata films.json


Make sure your database doesn't have any conflicts

You may get an error like this one:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '~/Desktop/django/testproject/film/fixtures/films.json': Could not load film.Movie(pk=None): UNIQUE constraint failed: film_movie.director

My code
If none of those worked here is the files I created:

testproject/film/models.py

from django.db import models
import datetime

GENRE_CHOICES = [("WESTERN", "WESTERN")]


# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(("year"), default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENRE_CHOICES, default="horror")
    synopsis = models.TextField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


testproject/film/fixtures/films.json

[
    {
        "model": "film.movie",
        "pk": null,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Django Unchained",
            "slug": "django-unchained",
            "year": 2012,
            "genre": "WESTERN",
            "synopsis": "<p>With the help of a German bounty-hunter, a freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.<p>",
            "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
            "excerpt": "A freed slave sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal plantation owner in Mississippi.",
            "added_on": "2024-06-01T09:43:19.754Z"
        }
    }
]



testproject/testproject/settings.py

"""
Django settings for testproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-cq0i6)l#kd69r)n_b$*_&3t0cn5bku8-0lxg=xoa4ix3j9aswe"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "film",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "testproject.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "testproject.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"



Hi Owen,
Thank you for your comprehensive answer, you were right! It was the trailing comma at the end that was the problem.
After I removed the comma I was able to load the data!
Thank you very much for your help on this,
Mus
